# Javascript Sum Distinct Rows into a input jqueryDatatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a tables filled with data using Jquery Datatables, what i want is to be able to sum all data from the distinc values of a column but when a dropdownlist value is changed and save the sum value into a new Html Input with Javascript Example:

I got my table filled with data like this:

```
|Platillo    |    PDV    |    Precio    |    Can    |    Date    |
------------------------------------------------------------------   
| Poz        |   REST    |     40       |      2    |  01/02/2016|
------------------------------------------------------------------  
| Tor        |   REST    |     50       |      2    |  02/02/2016|
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Zes        |   REST    |     100       |      2   |  01/02/2016|
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Poz        |   FUEM    |     60       |      2    |  01/02/2016|
------------------------------------------------------------------  
| Tor        |   FUEM    |     70       |      2    |  01/02/2016|
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Zes        |   FUEM    |     120       |      2   |  01/02/2016|
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Poz        |   VTSI    |     45       |      2    |  02/02/2016|
------------------------------------------------------------------  
| Tor        |   VTSI    |     57       |      2    |  01/02/2016|
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Zes        |   VTSI    |     10       |      2    |  02/02/2016|
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i want is to be able to sum all the values from the column 'Precio' into a 'Html Input Field' but i want to sum the totals of each distinct value from column 'PDV', and triggered by the value of a dropdown list, 
Ex: if user select's  Date '01/02/2016' i shoul fil my html Inputs with the sum of the data of all distinct value of column 'PDV' but only when they match the Date selected by the user '01/02/2016' looking for this output:

```html
<option value="">Todos</option>
 <option value="01/02/2016">@item</option> // USER SELECTS THIS VALUE
 <option value="02/02/2016">@item</option>
```

My input field are like follow:

```html
<input value="//TOTAL SUM FROM REST WHERE DATE IS EQUAL AS UsER SELECT '01/02/2016'" />
<input value="//TOTAL SUM FROM REST WHERE DATE IS EQUAL AS UsER SELECT '01/02/2016'" />
<input value="//TOTAL SUM FROM REST WHERE DATE IS EQUAL AS UsER SELECT '01/02/2016'" />
```

Im new to javascript and right now i have only be able to filter my Datatable based on the selected date but i need to sum all distincs values of my 'PDV' column each time user selects a date value how can i do it?

UPDATED:

i have the code of my dropdown filter y just need to know how to sum columns based on unique column items on my search javascript

This is my search code:

```js
     $('#sel0').on('change', function () {
                       dataTable.columns('.fechas').search(this.value).draw();
                       var datafecha = $(this).val();
                      
                   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a custom filter. Or take a look at this below to get an idea :

```
var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($('dropdown').val());

column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw(); 

var sum = column.data().unique().sum();

alert(sum);
```